# Gas stove trips GFCI outlet

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci, gas, stove

Any ideas why a LP gas range would suddenly start tripping GFCI breaker when the oven turns on? Should i be looking for a short somewhere and if so, where?

Comment: A dead short (low resistance short) should trip the overcurrent breaker. Although it could be a short to ground and if so it might trip the GFCI feature before current would build up to a value that would trip the overcurrent. Does your GFCI breaker have a light indicating whether it is being tripped by a ground fault or by overcurrent?

Comment: Pilot light or igniter? Electric oven?